# How to get name of both axis for an element in a 2d table in R

Tags: r, 2d, names, r-table

lets say ive got this table:

```r
print(thistable)

     axis1
axis2    1    2    3
   1  7584 9975 8187 
   2  8478 3624 4979
```

I want to get the names of each axis.
Example:
I want the names for element thistable[2]. What do i type to get something like: axis1:1, axis2:2?
Normal names() dont work, and row.names() work only for one axis.

Comment: Not sure if `colnames(thistable)` and `rownames(thistable)` can get what you want...

Answer (score 0):

its very dificult without a script but you can try with names(thistable) to see the element of your database

Comment: this returns NULL, I've tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I've figured an easy way of doing it is transforming the table to a dataframe and do get the indexes like I normally would